# Compare java.util.Date with MySQL date

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to compare a **java.util.date** with a **date** type in MYSQL with HQL and no solution found has solved my problem.

My method is

```
    public List<Person> getPersonByNameandBirth(String name, Date birth) {
        Session sesion = factoria.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Person> query = sesion.createQuery(
                "FROM Person WHERE name = :n AND birth = :date ORDER BY name",
                Person.class);
        ;
        query.setParameter("n", name);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(birth);
        System.out.println(date);
        query.setParameter("date", date);

        List<Person> people = query.getResultList();

        return people;
    }
```

With this code I get the exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Date (java.lang.String and java.util.Date are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.unwrap(JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.java:24)
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:48)
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)
    org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:648)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPreparedStatement(Loader.java:2131)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2108)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2040)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    com.spring.model.dao.PersonDAOImpl.getPersonByNameandBirth(PersonDAOImpl.java:152)
    com.spring.model.services.PersonService.getPersonByNameAndBirth(PersonService.java:53)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.getPersonByNameAndBirth(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.controller.PersonController.postPersonName(PersonController.java:147)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I have also tried just setting the parameter without DateFormat (no results, empty list).
Also, with to_char function (exception because it says it doen's exist).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `query.setParameter("date",birth)`

Comment: You don't have to use formatter, It will be handled automatically

Comment: Don't pass date values as Strings. Pass them as instances of `java.time.LocalDate`

Comment: I think you need to convert **java.util.data** to **java.sql.Date**, try this `java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( birth);` then  `query.setParameter("date", sqlDate);`

Comment: I have tried passing the parameter without formatting, and the Query doesn't return anything.
I'll try with sql.Date and with java.time.LocalDate and update the post with the one it works (or maybe they both work).
Thanks for your answers